# PostGIS ST_DWithin not working as expected

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, postgis

I have added a column location_point in Station model.

```
location_point: {
    type: Sequelize.GEOMETRY('POINT'),
},
```

When a new record is inserted into Station, I am converting longitude and latitude into POINT, and storing it in location_point column.

```
var location_point = {
    type: "Point",
    coordinates: [
         location_longitude,
         location_latitude,
    ],
};
```

Now, I need to find all systems within 50 meters of any specific point, named fixedPoint.
Below is the point:

I have written a query in Sequelize for PostgreSQL as below:

```
const fixedPoint = {
      type: "Point",
      coordinates: [end_location_longitude, end_location_latitude], 
};
const distanceInMeters = 50;

const stationsWithinRadius = await Station.findAll({
            where: db.where(
                db.fn(
                    "ST_DWithin",
                    db.col("location_point"),
                    db.fn(
                        "ST_SetSRID",
                        db.fn(
                            "ST_GeomFromText",
                            `POINT(${fixedPoint.coordinates[0]} ${fixedPoint.coordinates[1]})`
                        ),
                        4326
                    ),
                    distanceInMeters,
                    true // Use meters as the unit of distance
                ),
                true
            ),
        });
```

After that I have added multiple records in stations table, at distance less than 10m from the base point (fixedPoint)
When I execute the above query, it returns the records which are outside the radius (more than 50 meters aways)

The SRID is 4326.
I am using Postgresql, postgis and sequelize.

What can be the issue?

Comment: 4326 for geometry uses units of degrees.  So you are restricting it to within 50 degrees, not 50 meters.  If the column type were geography rather than geometry, then it would use meters (for distances).

Comment: Alright, thank you. 
If I want to keep type GEOMETRY, what should be the SRID for meters?
@jjanes

Comment: I have changed the type to GEOGRAPHY but still results are not that accurate.